# Facebook app invite iOS not working in production

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I have a strange issue, I am trying to implement iOS native Facebook invite.
It is working well with Testers, but unfortunately it is not working in production.

I read several articles on stackoverflow so yes I have :

- created a Facebook canvas with dummy url
- configured iOS app with real live App Store ID
- activated SSO, Deep linking...

Do you have any clue?

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Are you using App Invites, or Game Requests? What does your implementation look like? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: App invites. I am using : FBSDKAppInviteContent() with an appLink generated from FB. It doesn't work mean I don't see anything in the notifications on the native Facebook app if the users is not registered as a tester of my Facebook app.

Comment: Can you provide your app ID and the user IDs of the users that you test with?

Comment: Users won't always get push notifications depending on whether they've already seen your invite before, if they already have the app installed, and a whole host of other reasons (we don't want to spam people with push notifs). If your test users are getting push notifications, then it's working.